# Are these good ways to prove these statements about images,kernel and rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three (short proof questions, two of which I've done and wonder if they're good proofs).

If $A,B$ are any matrices such that $AB$ is defined, then we have
$\textbf{1.}$ ker$B$ $\subseteq$ ker$AB$,
$\textbf{2.}$ im$AB$ $\subseteq$ im$A$ $\quad$ and
$\textbf{3.}$ rank$AB$ $\leq$ rank$B$.
Is it true in general that im$AB$ $\subseteq$ im$B$?

Now, my proof for 1 is as follows:
Let $x \in \ker B$ so we have $Bx = \textbf{0}$ for all $x$. Hence, $ABx = \textbf{0}$ and the result follows.

Proof for 2.
Let $x \in im(AB)$ then we have that $ABv = x$ for some vector $v \in V$. Since $Bv$ generates another vector (I think this assumes that the codomain and domain are equal? I'm not sure), then we have $Aw = x$. Hence, $x$ is also in the image of $A$.

My attempt at 3.
By the rank-nullity theorem, $rank(AB) + nullity(AB) \leq \text{number of columns of}\quad AB$.
Then, $rank(AB) \leq \text{number of columns of}\quad AB.$
Now it looks like I want to show $rank(B) \geq \text{number of columns of}\quad AB$?

Also, I think that the answer to number 4 is: No. It is only true if $A,B $satisfy commutativity, i.e. $AB = BA.$

Sorry to throw so many questions at once, but they're essentially under the same branch, and they seem like intermediate proofs. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, won't the result (in the OP) follow if $im(AB) \subseteq im(B)$, then we can conclude that $rank(AB) \leq rank(B)$ since $dim(im(AB)) = rank(AB)$ and similarly for $B$?

Comment: It makes no sense to compare $\text{Im }AB$ and $\text{Im }B$ since they have different codomains

Comment: @JJR I'm not sure, I think that's what the information on my notes states word-for-word, I'll have another look soon. But aren't there some restrictions that could possible have $AB$ and $B$ to have the same output space?

Comment: ofcourse it is possible such as $A,B,C \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ i.e. $A,B,C$ quadratic of the same size